# Python Scrapy - output XML elements with same name

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

My goal is to generate XML which looks like:

```
<addional_image_links>test1</addional_image_links>
<addional_image_links>test2</addional_image_links>
<addional_image_links>test3</addional_image_links>
```

I am yielding  the results of my scrape like so:

```
yield  {
            'addional_image_links': 'test1',
            'addional_image_links': 'test2',
            'addional_image_links': 'test3',
        }
```

however the actual result is only the first one:

```
<addional_image_links>test1</addional_image_links>
```

If I change the element names, it works:

```
yield  {
            'addional_image_links_1': 'test1',
            'addional_image_links_2': 'test2',
            'addional_image_links_3': 'test3',
        }
```

However I need each of the outputted elements to have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't any good experience with scrapy, but according to provided source it seems like You're yielding a dictionary. Dictionary can't contain several items with same name. Best option on provided piece of code is one of:

1. Yield each image_link one by one;
2. Or (if You need to yield all results at one iteration) yield it as something like lists of sets.

```
yield  [
            ('addional_image_links', 'test1'),
            ('addional_image_links', 'test2'),
            ('addional_image_links', 'test3'),
        [
```